# Is there a way to apply a method to the ones that follow it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm a newbie working on making minor updates to a Rails 2 app. The StaticpageController is there to work with a content management system. Basically, there's a SQL database that holds a bunch of HTML code, and the controller methods tell the app which SQL record to pull the HTML from for which page on the app / site. There are a lot of pages; About and Advice are only two, which I've included in the snippet below. I want to also have these pages pull "links" from a separate table in the SQL database. I know that I can paste the "def link info" information into each and every method and it will work. I want to avoid doing with a simpler solution. Is there a better way?

```
class StaticpageController < ApplicationController
layout "main", :except => [:edit]
before_filter :login_required, :only => [:edit, :updatev]

def linkinfo
    @links = link.find(:all)
end

def about
   @page = Staticpage.find(12)
end

def advice
    @page = Staticpage.find(11)
end
```

and so on...

Comment: Have you tried `before_action :linkinfo`?

Comment: It's probably `before_filter` for a rails 2 app. `before_action` was introduced in Rails 4 if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks @jvillian for the lead, but Iceman was right about using before_filter. That did the job. Iceman, happy to accept answer if you post.